# SSRS - Sorting Aggregating fields

Tags: sql, sorting, reporting-services, aggregate-functions, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to sort a date column in a tablix(SSRS) and that column is aggregated. It does not sort the column and I have looked up different websites but could not get a clear answer on how to sort aggregated columns in SSRS.

FYI, I have added the sorting at the row group and also at Tablix properties but none of them seems to work.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

```
WITH T1 AS (SELECT        WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory, CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 120) 
                                                 AS CMonth, COUNT(CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 120)) AS Total_Complete
                        FROM            WorkManagementAsset INNER JOIN
                                                 WorkOrder ON WorkManagementAsset.Oid = WorkOrder.Asset INNER JOIN
                                                 WorkItem ON WorkOrder.Oid = WorkItem.WorkOrder INNER JOIN
                                                 InspectionDefectItem ON WorkItem.DefectItem = InspectionDefectItem.Oid AND WorkItem.Oid = InspectionDefectItem.WorkItem
                        WHERE        (NOT (InspectionDefectItem.DefectGroupName LIKE N'Re%'))
                        GROUP BY WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory, CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 120)
                        HAVING         (WorkManagementAsset.AssetCategory = @AssetCategory) AND (NOT (CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem.CompleteDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), 
                                                 WorkItem.CompleteDate, 120) IS NULL))), T2 AS
(SELECT        WorkManagementAsset_1.AssetCategory, CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem_1.DueDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem_1.DueDate, 120) AS DueMonth, 
                            COUNT(CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem_1.DueDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem_1.DueDate, 120)) AS Total_DUE
  FROM            WorkManagementAsset AS WorkManagementAsset_1 INNER JOIN
                            WorkOrder AS WorkOrder_1 ON WorkManagementAsset_1.Oid = WorkOrder_1.Asset INNER JOIN
                            WorkItem AS WorkItem_1 ON WorkOrder_1.Oid = WorkItem_1.WorkOrder INNER JOIN
                            InspectionDefectItem AS InspectionDefectItem_1 ON WorkItem_1.DefectItem = InspectionDefectItem_1.Oid AND 
                            WorkItem_1.Oid = InspectionDefectItem_1.WorkItem
  WHERE        (NOT (InspectionDefectItem_1.DefectGroupName LIKE N'Re%'))
  GROUP BY WorkManagementAsset_1.AssetCategory, CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem_1.DueDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem_1.DueDate, 120)
  HAVING         (WorkManagementAsset_1.AssetCategory = @AssetCategory) AND (CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem_1.DueDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), WorkItem_1.DueDate, 
                            120) <> '0'))
SELECT        T1_1.AssetCategory, T1_1.CMonth, T1_1.Total_Complete, T2_1.AssetCategory AS Expr1, T2_1.DueMonth, T2_1.Total_DUE
 FROM            T1 AS T1_1 FULL OUTER JOIN
                          T2 AS T2_1 ON T1_1.CMonth = T2_1.DueMonth
```

Comment: can you please post your data set or SQL

Comment: @maSTArHiAn: Added code as requested. I am trying to get the DueMonth Column sorted.

Comment: please format your query. thanks

Comment: @maSTArHiAn:Done formatting!

Comment: did you try putting order by  alias or actual field to sort?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn:Thanks, but it only works for the CompleteDate part which is in T1. I separated T1 from T2 and sorted T1 which works but it is not working for T2.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn: UPDATE:It works for both the queries individually but when I am joining it is not sorted!

Comment: you should be able to pin it down.. break your queries and understand the behaviour.. don't have much time to answer.

Comment: Got it sorted! Thanks for your time.